# Expectation maximisation, covariance step

Tags: matlab

I am implementing an algorithm that I know is correct (it has been provided) but I think I am not coding it correctly. Is the Matlab code for this equation?

[image: Maximisation Step]

Where:

- r is a 2x400 matrix
- x is a 1x400 vector
- mu is a 1x2 vector

  ```
  for (cGauss = 1:2)
  sumR = sum(r(cGauss,:));
  cov(1,cGauss) = sum(r(cGauss,:).*((x - mean(cGauss))*(x - mean(cGauss))'))/sumR;
  end
  ```

The covariance value I get after each iteration is in the order of 600's when it should slightly adjust up from 0.75.

Comment: Where is the `end` of the `for` loop? What error are you getting or incorrect output? And please remove the computer vision tag as it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Hi. The algorithm is part of a face detection algorithm out of Simon Prince's book on computer vision.

Comment: That's irrelevant. Expectation maximization is a general technique and  your question itself does't have relate to images or computer vision. I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting something like

> mean(cGauss,:)

instead of

> mean(cGauss)